# Offline Voice to text using java

Tags: java, offline, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

Is there any possible for creating offline voice recognition using java?and it will be print all words. now i am currently doing this task, i don't know How to start? please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this library its created for speech recognition 
[CMUSphinx](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4) and this is the documentation [docs](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/)

Comment: if u don't mind,i have doubt about cmusphinx,.. bcoz i want full english vocabulary!!, but on that api has few words only... please clear me!!

Comment: thanku bro....is there any source code link u have means post it bro :-)

Comment: well so far I haven't seen any good examples, but if  I do find something i Will post it here ;)